# PCA when missing data are meaningful

Tags: pca, data-visualization, missing-data, dimensionality-reduction

I'd like to use Principal Components Analysis, or some other dimension reduction technique, to help visualise relationships in a multidimensional dataset. However, the dataset has missing values. I know the standard procedure would be to impute the missing values, but I don't think this is appropriate in this case since the missing values are meaningful - i.e., they do not represent a lack of data, but certain variables being found to not be present in particular cases, which is interesting information to study.

Is there any way that I could include such meaningful missing data in a PCA?

I've considered replacing NAs with some value (e.g. a negative value - as suggested here: https://naniar.njtierney.com/reference/impute_below_all.html), but I don't know whether this would be valid.

EDIT: To clarify things a bit, in my dataset each case (row) represents a species, and each variable (column) is an ecological variable (e.g., rainfall, temperature, etc.) that could be relevant to a species and its value if it is (e.g., amount of rainfall in cm). My goal is to understand which variables and variable values most distinguish the different species. However, not all variables are relevant to all species (as determined by previous analyses), which creates missing values for those variables. A variable not being relevant to a species is an important observation though that could help distinguish it. Below is a heatmap illustrating the dataset. Grey cells indicate a particular variable not being relevant to a species.

[image: image.png]

Comment: Can you clarify what the actual variables are and what the reason for missing is?

Comment: Is NA the R-default missing value, or is it in fact "not-applicable"? Are you imputing pregnancy status for males? This question needs details and clarity to be answerable.

Comment: Since your objective is to visualize relationships rather than actual dimension reduction, it might be worth considering introducing binary indicators of (structural) missingness and proceeding to explore that augmented dataset.  Although this increases the number of dimensions, as an exploratory technique it could pay off by revealing useful associations between missingness and other variables.  There are many other possible ways to proceed, though, which is why others have begun asking you for further details.

Comment: Apologies for being vague. I've edited the question to try to clarify things a bit.

Comment: @Mark_1 Sorry no, I think you are clinging to abstract terminology here. "Networks" and "nodes" can mean anything. Every abstract term has to have a real thing that it measures or it's just that: abstract.

Comment: @AdamO Any better?

Comment: If a variable is not relevant to one species but is relevant to another, doesn't that give you a *guaranteed,* simple way to distinguish among the species??  It seems like you scarcely need to do any kind of analysis, statistical or otherwise, to account for these differences.

Comment: But there are many variables that they do share which differ only in value. So it's not just a matter of presence/absence to distinguish them, but of differing values as well. See the heatmap I've added.

Comment: But can't you at least first discriminate species based on which variables are meaningful for them, and then address each of the resulting groups as an independent subproblem?

Comment: I could if there was a clear pattern of which variables are meaningful to different groups, but as you can see above there is no clear pattern that would allow me to separate out different groups.